# Oracle SQL: Unique combinations within groups

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose a table (actually the result of a prior query) with data like this showing players and the position they play called player_tbl:

```
player_tbl

+-----------+----------------+----------+
| player_id |    position    |  player  |
+-----------+----------------+----------+
|         1 | Point Guard    | Johnson  |
|         2 | Point Guard    | Stockton |
|         3 | Point Guard    | Nash     |
|         4 | Point Guard    | Thomas   |
|         5 | Point Guard    | Payton   |
|         6 | Shooting Guard | Jordan   |
|         7 | Shooting Guard | Bryant   |
|         8 | Shooting Guard | Wade     |
|         9 | Small Forward  | Pippen   |
|        10 | Small Forward  | Bird     |
|        11 | Power Forward  | Rodman   |
|        12 | Power Forward  | Barkely  |
|        13 | Center         | Ewing    |
|        14 | Center         | Russell  |
+-----------+----------------+----------+
```

And from this table, I need to be able to **create all possible teams** made from these players.  Each team can be defined as ONE player of each position.  When even one player from a team is different, it is a different team.

Now, to make this worse, player_table is used for all sports.  So I CANNOT hard code the positions in the SQL.  Every time the query is run, the sport may be different and the positions need to be dynamic in that way.  On a basketball team, there are 5 positions, a baseball team would have 9 positions with different names.  And there are unknown number of players in the table for each position. I can however build a small subquery that will list each position on a team if a join or similar method would help.  Something like:

```
select distinct position from player_tbl

+----------------+
|   position     |
+----------------+
| Point Guard    |
| Shooting Guard |
| Small Forward  |
| Power Forward  |
| Center         |
+----------------+
```

The expected output is like this:

```
+---------+----------------+---------+
| team_id |   position     | player  |
+---------+----------------+---------+
| 1       | Point Guard    | Johnson |
| 1       | Shooting Guard | Jordan  |
| 1       | Small Forward  | Pippen  |
| 1       | Power Forward  | Rodman  |
| 1       | Center         | Ewing   |
| 2       | Point Guard    | Johnson |
| 2       | Shooting Guard | Jordan  |
| 2       | Small Forward  | Pippen  |
| 2       | Power Forward  | Rodman  |
| 2       | Center         | Russell |
| 3       | Point Guard    | Johnson |
| 3       | Shooting Guard | Jordan  |
| 3       | Small Forward  | Pippen  |
| 3       | Power Forward  | Barkely |
| 3       | Center         | Ewing   |
| 4       | Point Guard    | Johnson |
| 4       | Shooting Guard | Jordan  |
| 4       | Small Forward  | Pippen  |
| 4       | Power Forward  | Barkely |
| 4       | Center         | Russell |
| …       | …              | …       |
+---------+----------------+---------+
```

You can see that team 1 is only different from team 2 because the center is different.  And team 1 is only different from team 3 because the power forward is different.

If my math is right, the above data would produce 120 teams, 600 rows in the query result (5 point guards * 3 shooting guards * 2 SF * 2 PF * 2 C = 120 teams) and (120*5 positions=600 rows)

I have searched for hours to find a solution, but I probably lack the language to describe what is needed here in database terms.  Not exactly a cartesian product I don't think, but close.

Comment: If player_tbl contains players from multiple sports, is there a column indicating what sport the player plays? Otherwise players from different sports could get grouped as a "team"

Comment: player_tbl is the result of a prior query, so no, I doesn’t have that.  However, I can say that all players and positions shown in player_tbl are always for one and only one sport (though the sport changes each time).  So it is sort of the same thing I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `sport` column, you can use a hierarchical query and aggregate the positions and player names and then use a recursive sub-query to split the aggregated strings:

```sql
WITH teams (team_id, sport, positions, players) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM As team_id,
         sport,
         LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( position, ','), ',') AS positions,
         LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( player, ','), ',') AS players
  FROM   (
    SELECT p.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sport ORDER BY position) AS rnk
    FROM   player_tbl p
  )
  WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  START WITH rnk = 1
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR sport = sport
  AND    PRIOR rnk + 1 = rnk
),
team_players (team_id, sport, positions, players, idx, max_positions, position, player ) AS (
  SELECT team_id,
         sport,
         positions,
         players,
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT(positions, '[^,]+'),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(positions, '[^,]+', 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(players, '[^,]+', 1, 1)
  FROM   teams
UNION ALL
  SELECT team_id,
         sport,
         positions,
         players,
         idx + 1,
         max_positions,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(positions, '[^,]+', 1, idx + 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(players, '[^,]+', 1, idx + 1)
  FROM   team_players
  WHERE  idx < max_positions
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY team_id SET team_order
SELECT team_id,
       sport,
       position,
       player
FROM   team_players;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE player_tbl ( player_id, sport, position, player ) AS
SELECT  1, 'Basketball', 'Point Guard',    'Johnson'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Basketball', 'Point Guard',    'Stockton' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Basketball', 'Point Guard',    'Nash'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'Basketball', 'Point Guard',    'Thomas'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Basketball', 'Point Guard',    'Payton'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'Basketball', 'Shooting Guard', 'Jordan'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Basketball', 'Shooting Guard', 'Bryant'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Basketball', 'Shooting Guard', 'Wade'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'Basketball', 'Small Forward',  'Pippen'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Basketball', 'Small Forward',  'Bird'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Basketball', 'Power Forward',  'Rodman'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Basketball', 'Power Forward',  'Barkely'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'Basketball', 'Center',         'Ewing'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'Basketball', 'Center',         'Russell'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 'Netball',    'Goal Keeper',    'Kopua'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 'Netball',    'Goal Defence',   'Fowler'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 'Netball',    'Wing Defence',   'Sterling' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 'Netball',    'Center',         'Langman'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 19, 'Netball',    'Goal Shooter',   'Kumwenda' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 'Netball',    'Wing Attack',    'Watson'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 'Netball',    'Goal Attack',    'Ekenasio' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TEAM_ID | SPORT | POSITION | PLAYER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Basketball | Center | Russell |
> | 1 | Basketball | Point Guard | Johnson |
> | 1 | Basketball | Power Forward | Rodman |
> | 1 | Basketball | Shooting Guard | Bryant |
> | 1 | Basketball | Small Forward | Bird |
> | 2 | Basketball | Center | Russell |
> | 2 | Basketball | Point Guard | Johnson |
> | 2 | Basketball | Power Forward | Rodman |
> | 2 | Basketball | Shooting Guard | Bryant |
> | 2 | Basketball | Small Forward | Pippen |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | 120 | Basketball | Center | Ewing |
> | 120 | Basketball | Point Guard | Payton |
> | 120 | Basketball | Power Forward | Barkely |
> | 120 | Basketball | Shooting Guard | Wade |
> | 120 | Basketball | Small Forward | Pippen |
> | 121 | Netball | Center | Langman |
> | 121 | Netball | Goal Attack | Ekenasio |
> | 121 | Netball | Goal Defence | Fowler |
> | 121 | Netball | Goal Keeper | Kopua |
> | 121 | Netball | Goal Shooter | Kumwenda |
> | 121 | Netball | Wing Attack | Watson |
> | 121 | Netball | Wing Defence | Sterling |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9165e73ba6a9d2c2feae2fab3a80985c)*

---

If you don't have a `sport` column then just remove the references to if from the query:

```sql
WITH ranked_positions (player_id, position, player, rnk) AS (
    SELECT player_id,
           position,
           player,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY position) AS rnk
    FROM   player_tbl
),
teams (team_id, positions, players) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM,
         LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( position, ','), ','),
         LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( player, ','), ',')
  FROM   ranked_positions
  WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  START WITH rnk = 1
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR rnk + 1 = rnk
),
team_players (team_id, positions, players, idx, max_positions, position, player ) AS (
  SELECT team_id,
         positions,
         players,
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT(positions, '[^,]+'),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(positions, '[^,]+', 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(players, '[^,]+', 1, 1)
  FROM   teams
UNION ALL
  SELECT team_id,
         positions,
         players,
         idx + 1,
         max_positions,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(positions, '[^,]+', 1, idx + 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(players, '[^,]+', 1, idx + 1)
  FROM   team_players
  WHERE  idx < max_positions
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY team_id SET team_order
SELECT team_id,
       position,
       player
FROM   team_players;
```

- The `ranked_position` sub-query just assigns a numeric value from 1 to the number of unique positions to each position (giving identical positions the same number) in alphabetical order.
- The `teams` sub-query generates one row per possible team combination and contains two comma-delimited lists: the first is a list of unique positions; the second is a list of players in those positions. It is a hierarchical query and will work through all possible combinations of players-per-position.
- The `team_players` recursive sub-query then splits those comma-delimited lists back to into rows by finding successive sub-strings that do not contain commas. The result is that there is one-row-per-team-per-position.
- The `SEARCH` condition just ensures the previous recursive sub-query generates each row for each team in order; you could remove this and use an `ORDER BY` clause but its probably more efficient to generate it in the correct order rather than generating it in a different order and re-ordering it.
- The final `SELECT` just outputs the values.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=865204fb0c5f9a73f007efd3bd86128d)*

Comment: Brilliant!  Not sure I can say how it works, but it does.  I'm going to study and break this down to learn.  Many thanks!

Comment: @jsh144 Added a few notes and you can just run each successive sub-query to see what is happening [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=266dabca0642ec4ed347397105a3cb2d)

Comment: Thank you!  This looks similar to a LISTAGG approach, which is one thing I was experimenting with.  But it was beyond my creativity.  I just tried it with ORDER BY, and this did not seem to be overly taxing.  I like this because it allows me to use your final query in a WITH and build on it (SEARCH was causing an error in the WITH statement)

Comment: On the odd chance that there is a comma in the data (like a position='outfielder, LF' or a player='Jordan, Michael', I tried it with a pipe "|" character to delimit with instead of the comma.  It seems to work.  Not sure what would happen if I did find a comma in there

Comment: @jsh144 Yes, any character that is not going to be present in your data can be used as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the five positions, you can use a self join:

```
select pg.*, sg.*, sf.*, pf.*, c.*
from player_tbl pg cross join
     player_tbl sg cross join
     player_tbl sf cross join
     player_tbl pf cross join
     player_tbl c
where pg.position = 'Point Guard' and
      sg.posittion = 'Shooting Guard' and
      sf.posittion = 'Small Forward' and
      pf.posittion = 'Power Forward' and
      c.posittion = 'Center'
```

Comment: I don't know the positions unfortunately.  Is there a way to do that dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do what you want, it's a bit kludgy by creating an XML and then breaking it back apart, but it works:

```sql
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TEAM_RANK) AS TEAM_ID,
       t2.position,
       t2.player_name
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS TEAM_RANK, 
             XMLTYPE('<team>'||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH('<position>'||position||'</position><name>'||player_name||'</name></player>', '<player>')||'</team>') AS TEAM_XML
      FROM (SELECT position,
                   player_name,
                   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY position) AS POS_RANK
            FROM player_tbl)
      CONNECT BY POS_RANK = PRIOR POS_RANK+1
      START WITH POS_RANK = 1
      ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES) t,
XMLTABLE('/team/player'
         PASSING t.team_xml
         COLUMNS position VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'position',
                 player_name VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'name') t2;
```

Here is a quick description of what happens:

1. `SELECT` from the `player_tbl` adding a `DENSE_RANK` on position
2. Use hierarchical query to basically do a dynamic cartesian join for each position.
3. Create an `XML` with the team
4. Only return records at the max level
5. Use `XMLTABLE` to break the team XML into the necessary rows.

****Edit 1:Adding Recursive Subquery and Pure XML****

As I sat thinking about this answer, the 4000 character limit was really bugging me, so I refactored the query to use a recursive subquery and pure XML objects.  Here is the result:

```sql
WITH mod_player AS
(
  SELECT player_id, 
         position,
         player_name,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY position) AS POS_RANK
  FROM player_tbl
),
team_combo (lvl, player_path, team_xml) AS
(
  SELECT 1,
         TO_CHAR(mp.player_id),
         XMLELEMENT("player", XMLFOREST(mp.player_name AS "name", mp.position AS "position"))
  FROM mod_player mp
  WHERE mp.pos_rank = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tc.lvl+1,
         tc.player_path||' '||mp.player_id,
         XMLCONCAT(tc.team_xml, XMLELEMENT("player", XMLFOREST(mp.player_name AS "name", mp.position AS "position")))
  FROM team_combo tc
  INNER JOIN mod_player mp ON tc.lvl+1 = mp.pos_rank
)
CYCLE player_path SET is_cycle TO 'Y' DEFAULT 'N'
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TEAM_RAW) AS TEAM_ID,
       t2.position,
       t2.player_name
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS TEAM_RAW,
             XMLELEMENT("team", tc.team_xml) AS TEAM_XML
      FROM team_combo tc
      ORDER BY tc.lvl DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES) t,
XMLTABLE('/team/player'
         PASSING t.team_xml
         COLUMNS position VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'position',
                 player_name VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'name') t2;
```

Here is a DBFiddle showing the results...all 600 of them...for both queries([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9419aff92b74ee6cc5d0ffb572f24c21))

By the way, using the XML method would allow you to easily add columns like stats to the resulting team tables.  Then you could have some fun calculating things like which combination has the highest lifetime point total.

Comment: Thank you.  This is great, and could be as useful as MT0's answer, though a very different approach.  I tried it on a few sets of my data and it seems to work.  I did come across one parsing error, probably due to a character in the data that would need to be escaped for the XML parser not to trip over it.    Very creative approach, I would not have thought of it.